# How to read data from stdin without waiting for a newline character

Tags: c++, linux, console, pipe, stdin

I am writing a C++ program in Linux, that reads data from stdin and processes it.  Eventually I want to be able to cat a binary file and direct its output to my app.  So I need to be able to read binary and text data from stdin.  This program will be run from the bash shell.

I want my program to read characters in blocks of up to 50 characters, or until EOF.  Once it hits 50 characters or EOF it should immediately return control to my code.

In the program shown below, the read function waits until the user has entered at least 50 characters and the most recently entered character is a newline ('\n'). Once both these conditions are met, this function stops waiting, and copies 50 characters from stdin to the passed in char array.  But this is not what I want (since the user may pipe the stdout of their program which sends binary data, and may not contain a newline character).

I also tried std::istream::get(char* s, std::streamsize n) and reading one character at a time with std::istream::get() and both of these functions also wait until the most recently entered character is a newline.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and how can I achieve what I want.  (Is it even possible to read binary/non-text characters from stdin?)

```
std::streamsize bytesRead;
char block[51];

while (!std::cin.eof()) {
    std::cin.read(block, 50);
    bytesRead = std::cin.gcount();
    block[bytesRead] = '\0';
    std::cout << "block: [" << block << "]\n";
}
```

Comment: Your original code works fine if stdin is redirected from a program. The behaviour you see is specific to the terminal device; it has nothing to do with the `stdin` file descriptor.

Comment: Consider using **ncurses** which can put your terminal into a different non-buffered mode for input.  That kind of capability is not part of the standard C++ library.

Comment: @rici why would redirecting from a file cause the read to act differently?

Comment: @TSG: Because a file is not a terminal. The line buffering referred to here is implemented in the OS's terminal driver, not the C library. Files aren't really a good example, though; OP is more interested in pipes. In the case of pipes, it may be necessary to turn output buffering off in the program whose output is being redirected, but the program reading from `stdin` will certainly receive data as soon as it is sent; `istream::read` won't wait for a newline.

Comment: ... which is actually the same as the terminal. It's not that `istream::read` waits for a newline. It waits for 50 bytes or an end of file. It's the terminal which doesn't send until Enter is typed.